# Basic Class Library Project Missing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, class-library

I'm new into Visual Studio and c# development and I try to create a new Class Library Project. 
I can see only the "Class Library (.net Core)" model in my Visual Studio.
What can I do in order to have the basic one?

I'm using visual studio 2015 ce update 3.

Comment: What is the `basic one` ?

Comment: There is one without the ".net Core" specification.

Comment: Go to Installed -> Visual C# -> Class Library. You may need to install the desired framework version.

Comment: There isn't. I can find only Class Library (.net core) and Class Library (Portable) In Installed -> Visual C#

Comment: Which frameworks do you have in the combo box at the top?

Comment: If it's missing, try doing a *Repair* with the Visual Studio installer.

Comment: I tried to reinstall but it did not solve the problem

Comment: I've got .NET framework 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0

Comment: Have you tried issuing this command:  `devenv.exe /ResetSetttings`

Comment: No. How can I do?

Comment: Open a Visual Studio command prompt and enter that command.

Comment: I've tried with the ResetSettings command but there is nothing to do.